# LINQ-TO-SQL query not working with CSV file

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm reading a simple csv file from my program.  Here's what my csv file looks like:

```
NASDQ,O,
OTC,O,
NYSE,N,
TSE,T,
```

Here's my code to read the csv file:

```
string csvFile = @"x:\tech\SQL_IntlPricing\ExchangeLookup.csv";
string[] csvLines = File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);

var csvValues = csvLines
    .Select(l => new { 
        Exchange = l.Split(',').First(), 
        Lookup = l.Split(',').Skip(1).First ()});
```

So far, everything is fine with the code.  I'm using the following LINQ query:

```
from comp in Companies
where !comp.Coverage_status.Contains("drop")
select new
{
    FSTick = string.Format("{0}-{1}", comp.Ticker,
                csvValues
                    .Where(v => v.Exchange.Contains(comp.Exchange))
                    .Select(v => v.Lookup).FirstOrDefault())
};
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NotSupportedException: Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.
```

Basically, I'm trying to get the following results:

```
AAPL-O
MSFT-O
```

Is there a way for me to achieve the results I want using my LINQ query?

Comment: Can you post what `Companies` is/its assignment ? It looks like linq-to-sql will not support referencing the collection (sequence) which is being built by the linq statement itself (comp here). I would convert the whole expression to linq extension methods equivalent.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow.  Companies is an SQL table in my database.  What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: @Veverke would you provide an example, please?

Comment: I added my answer but after seeing that Cetin Bazoz did almost the same (I think his is better due the AsEnumerable(), so I deleted mine and upvoted his. I am going to temporarily undelete it in case it might help you. His solution does not do it ?

Comment: No.  Unfortunately, I'm not getting the results that I need.  I don't get any errors, though.

Comment: I re-added my answer, adding the full code I ran in recreating your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Companies are not a lot, then the simple solution would be:

```
    from comp in Companies.Where(c => !c.Coverage_status.Contains("drop")).AsEnumerable()
select new
{
    FSTick = string.Format("{0}-{1}", comp.Ticker,
                csvValues
                    .Where(v => v.Exchange.Contains(comp.Exchange))
                    .Select(v => v.Lookup).FirstOrDefault())
};
```

Otherwise you could do the filtering there like;

```
    from comp in Companies.Where( c => 
      csvValues.Select(cs => cs.Exchange).Contains(comp.Exchange) &&
      !c.Coverage_status.Contains("drop")
    ).AsEnumerable()
    select new
    {
        FSTick = string.Format("{0}-{1}", comp.Ticker,
                    csvValues
                        .Where(v => v.Exchange.Contains(comp.Exchange))
                        .Select(v => v.Lookup).FirstOrDefault())
    };
```

Comment: The Companies table has about 2000 companies.  Let met start with the 2nd option first.  I get an error:  `The name 'comp' doesn't exist in the current context.` 
The first option didn't give me any errors.  However, I'm not getting the results that I want.  I get the US companies working correctly, but not international, like TSE.  Here's what I'm getting for my results:  `AAPL-O, ALA-`.  Note:  ALA is listed on the TSE exchange.  So, I should be getting `ALA-T`.

Comment: I tried your update and I'm still not getting the results that I want.  Additionally, I thought the problem only affected internationals, but I'm not getting the OTC exchange as well.  Here's what I get now: `AAPL-O, ALA-, AMZN-`.  I should be getting: `AAPL-O, ALA-T, AMZN-O`.

Comment: I only corrected your code. I don't have your data. If you provide your data as code then we  could look into what is it.

Comment: Your code is right.  I had to trim the Exchange field from the table.  I didn't realize there were spaces.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment above, if converting the linq-sql expression into its extension methods syntax form is ok, you could do the following:

I created a list of companies just for the sake of the example. Company was defined as

```
   public class Company
    {
        public string Coverage_status { get; set; }
        public string Exchange { get; set; }
        public string Ticker { get; set; }
    }
```

Here's a full sample of how the code will would look like:

```
 List<string> csvLines = new List<string>
    {
        "NASDQ,O,",
        "OTC,O,",
        "NYSE,N,",
        "TSE,T,"
    };

    var csvValues = csvLines
    .Select(l => new
    {
        Exchange = l.Split(',').First(),
        Lookup = l.Split(',').Skip(1).First()
    });

    List<Company> companies = new List<Company>
    {
        new Company { Coverage_status = "aaa", Ticker = "123", Exchange = "NASDQ"},
        new Company { Coverage_status = "1521drop422", Ticker = "1251223", Exchange = "aaaaaaaa"},
        new Company { Coverage_status = "f2hdjjd", Ticker = "15525221123", Exchange = "TSE"}
    };

    var result = companies
        .Where(c => !c.Coverage_status.Contains("drop"))
        .Select(n => new
        {
            FSTick = string.Format("{0}-{1}", n.Ticker,
                csvValues
                    .Where(v => v.Exchange.Contains(n.Exchange))
                    .Select(v => v.Lookup).FirstOrDefault())
        });

    foreach (var r in result)
        Console.WriteLine(r.FSTick);
```

For the record, this code is definitely **not** performance-wise.

---

Output:

[image]

Comment: Odd!  I tried your suggestion with 1 addition:  `var companyList = Companies.Select(c => new Company { Ticker = c.Ticker.Trim(), Exchange = c.Primary_exchange.Trim(), Coverage_status = c.Coverage_status  });`.  I'm getting my original error now.